# Windows Installer - User Interface Form Visual Studio Deployment Project

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, setup-deployment, deployment-project

When you Include a User Interface Dialog Form as part of a Visual Studio Deployment Project (as seen below) When the user runs the installer and completes the text boxes where are these values then kept?

[image: Deployment Project]

I thought the values would be in the registry somewhere but i can't seem to find them...? Is there away to right the values into a file? or into the Settings.settings file of the application being installed?

[image: User install form]

Answer (score -1):

They are not kept anywhere. If you want to save them you need to do it yourself. It's straightforward just to create a registry entry in the setup project's IDE where in the value part you put property name in square brackets, such as [EDITA1]

Answer (score -1):

They are not kept anywhere. If you want to save them you need to do it yourself. It's straightforward just to create a registry entry in the setup project's IDE where in the value part you put property name in square brackets, such as [EDITA1]

Also the property names must be uppercase.

Answer (score -1):

These values not stored in the registry automatically.If you need these values in future you need to save these values in Registry or somewhere else.[You can access the vaues by using [SERVERNAME],[PN],[PT],etc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UV6Dp.png).

For saving in registry

You need to save the values in registry by accessing values [SERVERNAME],[PN],etc.[SERVERNAME,PN values saved in registry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Me6f9.png)